# Parsing ifconfig

Tags: shell, ifconfig

Trying to parse ifconfig output but I cannot for the life of me get the last part of this formatting to work.  Here's what I have:

```
ifconfig -a | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=RS="\n\n"} !/^lo/{print}' | sed 's/\s\+\s/=/g
s/.\overruns/=overruns/
/:[^=:]\+:/s/:[^=:]\+ /&=/g
s/^=/\t/
s/ *=$//
s/ *=/\n\t/g' | grep 'RX\|TX\|eth\|wlan\|dropped\|inet\|bytes\|BROAD'
```

This outputs this:

```
eth0: flags
    4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>
    inet 172.17.0.2
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2
    ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02
    RX packets 163
    bytes 7230 (7.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0
    dropped 0
    TX packets 1501
    bytes 111873 (109.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0
    dropped 0
```

I'm trying to add the RX and TX to their corresponding pairs like this:

```
eth0: flags
    4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>
    inet 172.17.0.2
    inet6 fe80::42:acff:fe11:2
    ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02
    RX packets 163
    **RX bytes** 7230 (7.0 KiB)
    RX errors 0
    **RX dropped** 0
    TX packets 1501
    **TX bytes** 111873 (109.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0
    **TX dropped** 0
```

Any push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do it with a python script it has tools  like regex, if you modifiy this, it will become even less readable.  Then you just need to do `ifconfig -a | python parseifconfig.py`

Comment: Note that `ifconfig` has been unmaintained for a long time; using it in new code is generally not wise. The same information is available from the `ip` command, which also knows about newer parts of the kernel and network stack that didn't exist back when `ifconfig` was written.

Comment: (f/e, if you have a named alias, `ifconfig` will completely ignore it unless you're using a version your distro locally patched; the only kinds of interface aliases it knows about are the numbered ones; `eth0:0`, `eth0:1`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit lame, but just append something like this to the code above:

```
| sed '/RX/{n;s/[^[:space:]]/RX &/};/TX/{n;s/[^[:space:]]/TX &/}'
```